# Expected Number of Draws without Replacement

Tags: probability, expectation

An urn contains ***a*** white balls, ***b*** blue balls and ***c*** red balls. Balls are drawn one by one without replacement. Find the expected number of draws needed to get all ***3*** colors.

Comment: I'm comfortable with the situation where there are only two colors. But getting stuck with this one.

Answer (score 1):

You draw a ball first, let's pretend for now that it is $a$. Now you have the urn with two balls problem. Compute the expected number of draws of $b,c$ needed to get both of them.  Scale that up by $\frac {a-1+b+c}{b+c}$ to account for the $a$'s you draw along the way.  This gives you the expected number of draws if you start with $a$.  You can compute the expected number if you start with $b$ and $c$ (or just permute the variables in your solution for $a$), then weight the three values by the fraction in the original bin.